# Как узнать географические координаты в Qt?

Tags: gps, qt, c++, desktop

Как узнать текущие географические координаты (широту и долготу) с помощью C++ или Qt?

Comment: а где будет код выполнятся - на телефоне или на декстопе?

Comment: На декстопе.

Comment: тогда Вам нужен gps датчик. Или гадать через IP. Можно попробовать ещё использовать телефон с gps.

Comment: Мне необходимо это для компьютерной программы. Может какие-то API помогают в этом? Я не умею ими пользоваться. Вот к примеру что-то подобное обсуждается на сайте Яндекс: http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/geolocation_api

Comment: Все эти API основаны на объекте `navigator.geolocation`, который "встраивается" в новые веб-браузеры. Поэтому надо понять какая точность нужна, диапазон решений для десктопных приложений - от IP или провайдера (если они доступны) до подключения внешних устройств.

Comment: Мне сильная точность не нужна. Конечная цель: определить город. А если использовать IP, то все равно наверное необходимо будет прибегнуть к какого-нибудь веб-сервису или как?

Comment: Баз для работы с IP навалом, начиная с [MaxMind GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/). Можно и к внешним сервисам запросы делать, и локально базы держать, только не забывать их регулярно обновлять. Другое дело что наружный IP часто будет недоступен, да и ошибаться они могут запросто.

Comment: А как Google Карты и Apple Карты определяют местоположение на декстопе, причем с полной точностью? Или там идет уже чисто веб-программирование?

Comment: Все эти API получают данные из объекта `navigator.geolocation`, который имеет [стандартный интерфейс](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html), но в каждом браузере (и в каждой системе) может быть реализован как угодно. В общем и целом - комплексно: wifi, данные провайдера и т.д., и т.п.
Задача эта далеко не тривиальная, и, если честно, я не вижу огромного смысла в ней для десктопного приложения. Куда проще и точней явно спросить место у юзера :)